# Dataset for Watson Assistant

Tags: dataset, websphere, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm using IBM Watson Assistant and I have built a very good and functional chatbot and I want to make even better.
I'm trying for a while to find a dataset to import entities and intents for IBM Watson Assistant. I have already found some data from datasearch google and other sites but I'm searching for booking system and customer support data. Is there any site that I can find the right format for Watson or any data from the above.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the trained intents and entities are customized within each company for its use-cases, and it will be hard to find a ready plug and play intents that fits your usecase 100%. But you can get the data to start training Watson assistant yourself using examples from datasets available on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?search=call%20center).